# chaincode instantiate giving error in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

Hello Everyone i am working on setup of  fabric default first-network in kubernetes. But when i am instantiate the chaincode it gives me error. Please check below are my peer logs.

```
  2019-07-22 07:25:02.134 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 066 [mychannel][c4b4e2ae] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: container exited with 0
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*RuntimeLauncher).Launch.func1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/runtime_launcher.go:63
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333
chaincode registration failed
```

Getting this error on Cli :-

```
 2019-07-22 07:24:58.263 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2019-07-22 07:24:58.264 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0
```

Here is my complete file :- `---

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: peer0-svc
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: peer0
  replicas: 1 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: peer0
    spec:
     securityContext:
      runAsUser: 0
      runAsGroup: 0
      fsGroup: 0
     volumes:
      - name: peer0-run
        hostPath:
          path: /var/run/
      - name: peer0-main
        hostPath:
          path: /var/hyperledger/peer0
      - name: peer0-msp
        hostPath:
          path: /home/harpartap/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp
      - name: peer0-tls
        hostPath:
          path: /home/harpartap/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls                                                             
     containers:
      - name: peer0
        image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
        env:
        - name: CORE_PEER_ID
          value: "peer0"
        - name: CORE_PEER_ADDRESS
          value: "peer0-svc:7051"
        - name: CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS
          value: "0.0.0.0:7051"
        - name: CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS
          value: "peer0-svc:7052"
        - name: CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS
          value: "0.0.0.0:7052"
        - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP
          value: "peer0-svc:7051"        
        - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT
          value: "peer0-svc:7051"
        - name: CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT
          value: "true"
        - name: CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID
          value: "Org1MSP"
        - name:  CORE_VM_ENDPOINT
          value: "unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock"
        - name: FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC  
          value: "INFO"
        - name: CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_SHIM
          value: "debug"
        - name: CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL
          value: "debug"
        - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED
          value: "false"
        - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION
          value: "true"
        - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER
          value: "false"
        - name: CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED
          value: "true"
        - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE
          value: "/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt"
        - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE
          value: "/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key"
        - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE
          value: "/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt"         
        ports:
         - containerPort: 7051
         - containerPort: 7052  
        volumeMounts:
        - name: peer0-run
          mountPath: "/host/var/run/"
        - name: peer0-main
          mountPath: "/var/hyperledger/production"                          
        - name: peer0-msp
          mountPath: "/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp"
        - name: peer0-tls
          mountPath: "/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls"
        workingDir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
        command: ["peer","node","start"]  

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: peer0-svc
  labels:
    run: peer0-svc
spec:
  type: ClusterIP 
  selector:
    name: peer0
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 7051
    targetPort: 7051
    name: grpc
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 7052
    targetPort: 7052
    name: events
```

`
Above is the complete deployment and service file for the peer.

Logs on orderere:-

```
2019-07-25 06:38:18.997 UTC [orderer.common.server] Start -> INFO 007 Beginning to serve requests
2019-07-25 06:54:19.931 UTC [fsblkstorage] newBlockfileMgr -> INFO 008 Getting block information from block storage
2019-07-25 06:54:19.939 UTC [orderer.commmon.multichannel] newChain -> INFO 009 Created and starting new chain mychannel
2019-07-25 06:54:19.945 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 00a streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=10.244.1.142:56806 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=43.342982ms
2019-07-25 06:54:19.951 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> WARN 00b Error reading from 10.244.1.142:56804: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-07-25 06:54:19.951 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 00c streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=10.244.1.142:56804 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=51.093714ms
2019-07-25 06:54:47.606 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> WARN 00d Error reading from 10.244.1.142:56814: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-07-25 06:54:47.607 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 00e streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=10.244.1.142:56814 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=208.471147ms
2019-07-25 06:54:47.607 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] Handle -> WARN 00f Error reading from 10.244.1.142:56816: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-07-25 06:54:47.607 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 010 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=10.244.1.142:56816 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=206.512901ms
2019-07-25 06:55:00.174 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> WARN 011 Error reading from 10.244.1.142:56822: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-07-25 06:55:00.175 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 012 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=10.244.1.142:56822 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=32.203309ms
2019-07-25 06:55:00.175 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] Handle -> WARN 013 Error reading from 10.244.1.142:56824: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-07-25 06:55:00.175 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 014 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=10.244.1.142:56824 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=30.174302ms
2019-07-25 06:56:15.422 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] Handle -> WARN 015 Error reading from 10.244.1.142:56844: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-07-25 06:56:15.423 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 016 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=10.244.1.142:56844 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=3.7282556
```

57s

Comment: Post the peer logs that you're trying to install the chaincode, while instantiating golang chaincode, it will download the required packages and try to compile.
If you try to observe the 'docker ps -a', at some point your chaincode image build will fail.
These logs available in peer, where you're trying to instantiate.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try adding following   GODEBUG: "netdns=go" to your ConfigMap or env

Comment: i added it but nothing more than these error. @mohmmad

Comment: what is the log on orderer ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to instantiate chaincode, you need to run your pod in privileged mode to be able to access a Docker socket inside the peer container. This could be sometimes an issue if your kubernetes security policy does not allow to do this.

Comment: so i need to give root user privilege to pod ?

Comment: basically yes, give it a try

Comment: Can you add your peer-base.yaml file?and your env details as well?

Comment: @RisabhSharma please check my post i added the deployment file.